# PROBLEMAS AO EDITAR COLUNAS COM PANDAS

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

planilha_report = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx") #LENDO ARQUIVO INICIAL

#planilha_report

planilha_maiuscula = planilha_report[["Categoria","Origem de Abertura", "Serviço (Completo)", "Criado por"
                                     , "Serviço (1º Nível)", "Assunto", "Cliente (Organização)", "Responsável: Equipe",
                                     "Causa Raiz de ToIP", "Causa Raiz de Dados", "Causa Raiz de Vídeo", "Resolução"
                                     , "Indicador do SLA de Solução", "Descrição"]].str.upper()

planilha_maiuscula
```

Ao tentar rodar o código acima retorna um erro de `AttributeError: DataFrame object has no attribute 'str'`.

Preciso transformar todos os valores das colunas para `upper`.

Comment: O método `.str` só funciona em séries... Veja a resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme dito nos comentários, o método `.str` somente funciona em tipo `pandas.core.series.Series`

Use um loop pelas colunas:

```
for col in planilha_report.columns:
    planilha_report[col] = planilha_report[col].str.upper()
```

Comment: Ao adicionar o loop acima o script retorna o seguinte erro: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: Resolvi, tinha colunas minhas formatadas com Datetime, após a conversão para Object o loop funcionou! muito obrigado!

Comment: Que bom que funcionou. Achando pertinente, marque a resposta como aceita.